# Troubles with installing Katoolin

Tags: 18.04, katoolin

```
   63  git clone https://github.com/LionSec/katoolin.git
   64  cp katoolin/katoolin.py /usr/bin/katoolin
   65  chmod +x /usr/bin/katoolin
   66  sudo katoolin
sudo: katoolin: command not found
```

This about sums it up I hope. I am running a relatively fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 Xfce Desktop Enviroment.

```
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              4
Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2320 CPU @ 3.00GHz
```

Comment: Try `sudo /usr/bin/katoolin`. If that doesn't help, Please post the output of `sudo sh -c 'echo "$PATH"'`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure all run ok? I believe commands in lines 64 and 65 need be sudoed too. Try:

```
git clone https://github.com/LionSec/katoolin.git
sudo cp katoolin/katoolin.py /usr/bin/katoolin
sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/katoolin
sudo katoolin
```

Hope it help you